# PPA for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: software-installation, software-sources

I have been trying to add a PPA for Ubuntu 12.04 and keep getting errors like:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/<release-main>/Release.gpg   
Unable to connect to linux.dropbox.com:http:

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/tucan/unstable/ubuntu/dists/prec/Release.gpg  
Unable to connect to ppa.launchpad.net:http:
```

Please help.

Comment: How did you add your PPA?

Answer (score 0):

In the Dropbox entry, `<release-main>` needs to be replaced with `precise`, and in the tucan PPA entry, `prec` needs to be replaced with `precise`.

Open up Software Sources or Software & Updates, and switch to the Other Software tab. Find the Dropbox entry and click Edit. Then, replace `<release-main>` with `precise`. Do the same with the tucan PPA entry, but replace the `prec` with `precise`.